# Qt5: Не запускается тест

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, юнит-тесты, mingw

Написал я для своего шуточного метода тест, пытаюсь его запустить вот так:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    double a, x, b, c;
    //Equ *obj = new Equ();
    //cin >> a >> x >> b >> c;
   // obj->compute( a, b,  c,  x);
    test lab;
    return app.exec();
}
```

а он не запускается...

```
D:\Qt\5.12.2\mingw73_32\include\QtTest\qtestcase.h:419: ошибка: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest14compare_helperEbPKcPcS2_S1_S1_S1_i'
```

в тестовых файлах написано такое:

```
файл test.h

#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <equ.h>
#include <QtTest/QTest>
class test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit test(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:

private slots:
 void lab();


};

#endif // TEST_H

файл test.cpp

    #include "test.h"

test::test(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}
void test::lab()
{
    Equ a;
    QCOMPARE(a.compute(1,2,2,-5), -3);
    QCOMPARE(a.compute(0, 1,2,3), 1);
    QCOMPARE(a.compute(-5, 2, 1, 3), 3.3333333);

}
//QTEST_MAIN(test)
```

Как запустить тестирование?

P.S. Про qExec() знаю, но эта штука даже не собирается. Опять же, почему-то не генерируется moc, хотя qmake я запускал неоднократно. Компилятор MinGW, версия фреймворка 5.12.2
прикладываю pro файл, по просьбе одного из отвечавших

```
QT -= gui testlib

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        equ.cpp \
        main.cpp \
        test.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    equ.h \
    test.h
```

касательно `#include <QTest>` все на изображениях
[image: QtTest]
[image: QTest]

Comment: Либа может не подключена

Comment: `QT += libtest` имеется. Кстати он moc-файл на тестирующий класс почему-то не делает.

Comment: Приведите содержание pro-файла в вопросе.

Comment: Во-первых не `QT += libtest`, а `QT += testlib`. Вo-вторых недостаточно создать класс теста, надо запустить тест с помощью конструкции `QTest::qExec(&lab, argc, argv);`. В-третьих в моем коде было просто `#include <QTest>`.

Comment: QTest сам по себе подключаться не хочет

Comment: В Вашем проектном файла `QT -=`, а должно быть `+=`

Comment: Поправил. Все запускается. Теперь проблема теперь с запуском самого теста. указание на запуск из коммента @BeardedBeaver я дал, а тест не запускается. moc'а как не было для test.h так и нет, не смотря на многократный запуск qmake.
P.S. почему-то к слову не заводится и консолька. Т.е. процесс есть а окна консольки с ним нет...

Comment: вы pro файл поправили с `-=` на `+=`? сейчас в вопросе вы исключаете `testlib`, из-за этого оно и не видит `QTest`

Comment: да, я поправил его так как вы и сказали. Теперь он почему-то moc Не создает и сама программа не запускается...